# How can I remove Swagger lines from Jacoco and Sonar Code Coverage

Tags: sonarqube, swagger, code-coverage, jacoco

I am using Swagger for API Documentation due to which we are using Swagger Annotation like `@ApiOperation, @ApiResponses, @ApiImplicitParams` etc. covering at-least 3-5 lines per api.

Sonar is considering these lines for overall code coverage metric. So is there a way with which we can let Sonar or Jacoco ignore Swagger annotations for overall Code Coverage Analysis.

Comment: did you find any solution? I am also experiencing the same issue.